# How to change Ruby version for Homebrew in macOS in Travis CI?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, travis-ci

Trying to run

```
if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then brew install python3; fi
```

in `before_install`, I end up with

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:12:in \`<main>': Homebrew must be run under Ruby 2.3! (RuntimeError)  

The command "if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then brew install python3; fi" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.

/Users/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 166: shell_session_update: command not found
```

So I assume the issue here is that `ruby` is on version 2.0, which I confirmed with `ruby --version`. The funny thing is, my builds just stopped working all of the sudden, without any change to .travis.yml.
So how do I actually change Ruby versions?

Might be important to not, that before `git clone` is run I get this:

```
$ rvm use

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin' is not at first place,

         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,

         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',

         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p648'.
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem installing mutt. I'm reading through the following, don't know if relevant https://discuss.circleci.com/t/homebrew-must-be-run-under-ruby-2-3-runtimeerror/17232/6

Comment: Seems like you are using rvm to manage versions of Ruby. Is that right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your choices seem to be to either use

```
brew update
brew install whatever
```

or

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install whatever
```

The advice in [travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx/) to not do a `brew update` if it doesn't seem to be needed seems to leave you at risk of random breakage when brew's ruby requirement is changed...

Answer (score 9):

- brew update
- brew install ruby-build
- brew install rbenv
- rbenv install [version_required]
- rbenv global [version_required]

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Core projects: you can avoid using brew by not using Travis' default .NET Core but installing it using the Microsoft's .NET core sh script. I used to have `mono` and `dotnet` version definitions set which I've found were not needed after switching to the sh script. I was able to fix the `Homebrew must be run under Ruby 2.3!` error by removing those two definitions (although I then had to update `libunwind8` on Linux before doing the .NET core install).

Here's the complete .travis.yaml for running .NET core project test on osx and linux.

```
language: csharp

before_install:
  - if [ "$OS" = "linux" ]; then sudo apt-get install libunwind8; fi

script:
  - wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh && chmod +x dotnet-install.sh
  - ./dotnet-install.sh --version 1.1.4 --install-dir $HOME/.dotnet
  - $HOME/.dotnet/dotnet restore
  - $HOME/.dotnet/dotnet test YOUR_CSPROJ_FILE_PATH

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      env: OS=linux
    - os: osx
      osx_image: xcode9
      env: OS=osx

branches:
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me with --version 2.0.0 because my projects need the 2.0 .NET Core SDK. Thanks for sharing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

running `brew update` before `brew install package_name`

Answer (score 0):

I got success on changing Ruby version for Homebrew in macOS, creating a personal access token on GitHub and setting it on my Mac as:

https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=gist,public_repo&description=Homebrew

And then set the token with:

```
export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN="your_new_token"
```

> If you already has this token set, you can clear them with:
>
> ```
> printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\n" | git credential-osxkeychain erase
> ```